# Is it possible to encrypt data in Laravel with APP_KEY which differ per user?

Tags: laravel, encryption, architecture

I'm using the Laravel framework to encrypt almost all data in a MySQL database. This is a requirement, due to privacy concerns.

Laravel uses an application specific APP_KEY as the main key to handle encryption and decryption (OpenSSL / AES-256-CBC cipher).

I wonder: Is it easy (or is there a package) to generate an APP_KEY on a user base? So each user get's an APP_KEY (f.e. USER_APP_KEY) to handle all user specific data?

I think this adds an extra security layer. So even if the data is stolen and one user is somehow decrypted, the rest of the data remains useless to the attacker.

Or am i overcomplicating things and is a single APP_KEY safe enough?

---

Already tried:

Search for existing packages for Laravel framework.
Generic Google search for examples.

Comment: If each user has their own key, that key must be stored somewhere. For practical purposes, probably somewhere in the database together with the user data. Which puts the key right next to the encrypted data. Which makes the whole thing somewhat pointless.

Comment: Currently an APP_KEY is stored in an .env variable in the filesystem outside the webroot. A solution could be to add some sort of data structure outside the webroot which links users to there own APP_KEY.

Comment: you can combine user_id and static key as you have primary key in id column in user table id field so it will generate diff key every time.

Comment: @Peer That's not typically a sensible approach. Web servers should be stateless and scalable, so assume you have more than one instance of that server running for load balancing purposes. In that case requiring a data store on the web server in addition to a database becomes rather impractical.

Comment: @sandy Yes, that's a possibility, but that undermines the main point: *"even if the data is stolen and one user is somehow decrypted, the rest of the data remains useless to the attacker"*. If an attacker can decrypt *one* user, they have figured out the static key, and the "dynamic" key is right there in the user data.

Comment: In general, encryption only makes sense if the attacker doesn't have the key. You should ask yourself what the probability of an attacker getting the data, but not the key is. If you store the key in a file/environment variable somewhere, chances are they'll get the key together with the data when attacking your server. The only case where encrypted database data is useful is if a backup leaks, for example, without the accompanying key. How likely is that? May it be enough to encrypt your backups? What are you *really* protecting against?

Comment: @deceze In the EU it is the law to protect personal data as much as you can. In my case the database (different server) is seperated from the key (another server, key outside webroot). So when the database is hacked, the attacker gets nothing.

Comment: I don’t think EU laws demand *encryption* specifically. And again, what’s the most likely attack vector to “hack the database”? More often than not it’s through the public facing web server. So once an attacker is there, the key stored on the web server is usually a goner as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can generate the key for every user and store it into the `users` table.
Following code sample is to generate a key.

```
'key' => encrypt($this->generateRandomString(16))

private function generateRandomString($n) { 

    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; 

    $randomString = ''; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { 

        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1); 

        $randomString .= $characters[$index]; 

    }      

    return $randomString; 

}
```

When you need to decrypt the content, you can do it as follows.

```
$encrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter($key);
$decrypted = $encrypter->decrypt($encryptedContent);
```

For additional security, I suggest you to encrypt the user based key using APP_KEY.
Then store encrypted key in the database.

When decrypt, you need to decrypt the key first. After you can decrypt the content using user based key.
Then some one need to get the content need to know both two keys which are user key and app key.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with a single APP_KEY. There's is no package that i'm aware of that handles this. And based on the comments, it doesn't do any good in terms of security.